# How to merge excel file without losing its format

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So here is a sample of my excel layout:

[image: Sample excel layout]

But after merging it has two header and loses the layout.

[image: After merging excel sheet]

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r"C:/Users//"
fname = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")

result_DFs1 = pd.DataFrame()
result_DFs2 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in fname:  
    try:
        df1 = pd.read_excel(i,sheet_name = "Test1")
        result_DFs1 = pd.concat([result_DFs1, df1])

    except:
        pass

for i in fname:  
    try:
        df2 = pd.read_excel(i,sheet_name = "Test2")
        result_DFs2 = pd.concat([result_DFs2, df2])

    except:
        pass

with pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_to_excel.xlsx') as writer:    
    result_DFs1.to_excel (writer, sheet_name='Test1')    
    result_DFs2.to_excel (writer, sheet_name='Test2')
```

Is there a way I can just have one header and without losing the excel layout format?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of your sheets and only include headers for the first one. Something like:

```
first = True
for i in fname:  
    try:
        if first:
            df1 = pd.read_excel(i,sheet_name = "Test1", skiprows=0, header=0)
            first = False
        else:
            df1 = pd.read_excel(i,sheet_name = "Test1", skiprows=1, header=None)

        result_DFs1 = pd.concat([result_DFs1, df1])

    except:
        pass
```

Comment: once it merges it is displaying the header is still there:

Comment: do you have joined cells or empty rows at the top of your sheet? adapt `skiprows` and `header` accordingly